# SyntaxError by define a python variable that was extracted from a python program

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables, syntax-error

i am looking for some help with python3.

My problem is a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when i define a variable in python that i extracted from the program it self.

Short: I wanna replace a huge function by his own result.

For that i printed the wanted variable and replaced the function call with the output from print().

See here:

```
ecu = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ECU')
print("ecu=",ecu)
```

The output:

```
ecu= [<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c108470>, <DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c099af8>]
```

But when i insert that variable to my code, i get this error:

```
ecu= [<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c108470>, <DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c099af8>]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ecu= [<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c108470>, <DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c099af8>]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

So what is the right way to replace this function call with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

*`ecu` is a list of `DOM Element` instances* - strings like `<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c108470>` are `DOM Element` object [string representations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr).

You probably meant to just use the `ecu` variable. For instance, here is how you can get the text inside the nodes:

```
for node in ecu:
    print(node.childNodes[0].data)
```

Comment: Aha....okay. I tried:
`for node in ecu:
    print(node.childNodes[0].data)`
but there was no answer.

Comment: Then i tried:
`for node in self.ecuObj:
            print(node.childNodes[0])`
Then i get this:
`<DOM Text node "'\n\t\t\t\t'">`

Comment: @HansMaulwurf that was just an example. I don't know what are you planning to do with the list.

Comment: But how can i store the output of `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ECU')` to set a variable manually?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you did. What exactly is `<DOM...>`? You know where that thing came from? It came from `obj.__repr__()` which is a fallback for `obj.__str__()`. So if you insert the `__repr()__` values i.e `"<DOM..>"`(see the quotes) and then `eval()` the expression or `exec()` the statement, you get back the intended result.

But I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish here with `"<DOM..>"`

Comment: If i use quoteslike this: `self.ecuObj = ["<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c108470>", "<DOM Element: SERVICE-INTERFACE at 0x7fc73c099af8>"]` then the proram run, but i get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'childNodes'`. A String might not be the right answer.

Comment: It won't work that way. Try `repr(ecu)`. You will get the `ecu.__repr__()`.That string can be converted back to the corresponding object by `eval()`.

Comment: `repr(ecu)` gives me no output. And `print(repr(self.ecuObj))` gives me the same output as i mentiond in my question above.